# sorting document outline in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6

in the document outline the scenes are sorted as they are added to the storyboard. Now after having added all scenes I want to sort them in a "content logic" to find them easier. Is it possible to re-arrange them manually and if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via storyboard xml. Just right click storyboard and open it as an xml. You should be able to see tag "scenes" which contains "scene" which is viewcontroller. The order presented under "scenes" tag correspond to the one you can see under document outline.

As you may assume just copy paste the whole "scene" content to the place you want to see it in document outline.